# Warp error: error[E0277]: the trait bound `impl warp::Future: warp::filter::FilterBase` is not satisfied

Tags: rust, type-definition, rust-warp

Warp is returning the error,

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `impl warp::Future: warp::filter::FilterBase` is not satisfied
  --> src/http.rs:31:26
   |
31 |     let routes = index().or(users());
   |                             ^^^^^^^ the trait `warp::filter::FilterBase` is not implemented for `impl warp::Future`
```

I have essentially this,

```
pub async fn users() -> impl Filter<Extract = impl warp::Reply, Error = warp::Rejection> + Clone {
  # stuff
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

[`or`](https://docs.rs/warp/0.3.1/warp/trait.Filter.html#method.or) takes a functions that returns a `Filter`. Your function is marked `async`, and returns a `Future<Output = Filter>`. You can instead use [`or_else`](https://docs.rs/warp/0.3.1/warp/trait.Filter.html#method.or_else), the async version of `or`:

```rust
let routes = index().or_else(users());
```

Comment: OrElse doesn't return a filter though, when I use it I get that my function has to take arguments. `.or` does not require it's functions take arguments:  `.or(warp::header("x-forwarded-for"))` [Like here](https://github.com/seanmonstar/warp/blob/master/examples/routing.rs#L63) no arguments.

Comment: I get these errors `OrElse<T, F>` **_doesn't satisfy `<_ as warp::Future>::Output = Result<_, _>`** **doesn't satisfy `_: warp::Future`**

Comment: "OrElse doesn't return a filter though" Yes it does, `OrElse` is a `Filter`.

Comment: `or_else` receives a potential `Rejection`, and must return a `TryFuture` (`Future<Output = Result<>>`)

Comment: You can trivially update your function signature to match that.